# How to get integer from json object async in android?

Tags: android, json, asynchronous

**Original Question -**

I was following a tutorial on json in android, but having problem to get json value using Async in android. First I created jsonparser class and added following to it -

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
//      Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
//      Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

Then to use this in fragment by async i tried -

```
    class getTopicId extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
          pDialog.setMessage("Getting Topic of the Day ...");
          pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          pDialog.setCancelable(true);
          pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
      protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
      JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
      // Getting JSON from URL
      JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://medicalguru.in/android/tod.php");
      return json;
    }
     @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       pDialog.dismiss();
       try {
           topic_id = json.getInt("value");    
      } 
       catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
       finally {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "topic id -"+topic_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
     }
}
```

but the app is crashing when i execute this async.
my logcat shows -

```
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at in.medicalguru.DailyTestFragment$getTopicId.onPostExecute(DailyTestFragment.java:786)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at in.medicalguru.DailyTestFragment$getTopicId.onPostExecute(DailyTestFragment.java:1)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-06 15:07:03.123: E/AndroidRuntime(2041):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The link mentioned above in the code outputs as -

```
{"value":1}
```

when opened normally, but when I run in async it says err related to nullpointer?
Couldn't figure, where I am making mistake ?

---

**Edit 1 :**
**tod.php** code (Since Matthew has pointed something which I dont understand, so it may be helpful)

```
<?php
$today = date("Ymd");
switch($today){
case 20140304 :
$tod["value"] = 24;
break;
case 20140305 :
$tod["value"] = 25;
break;
case 20140306 :
$tod["value"] = 1;
break;
default:
$tod["value"] = 1;
break;
}
echo json_encode($tod);
?>
```

---

**Edit 2 :** **Found the problem (fully for me) but Partly in Real** - A special thanks to Matthew for his idea, to uncomment the error logs of function getJSONFromUrl(String url). I got a new error line in logcat -

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

After little bit of search on google and stacksoverflow I found one suggestion to **change chrSet to UTF-8 instead of iso-8859-1**. and it worked for my requested url in both situations (with or without WWW - suggestion to test, by nikis). But this answer is partial real, because, now 2 unanswered questions developed -
1. **Why did chrSet change worked?** In future, what chrSet to be used, to avoid this problem, and what's the use of other one chrSet?
2. Matthew has replicated my Json to his server mwesly.com/test/ . Trial on his server, logcat shows following error in all cases (with or without WWW, with or without using index.php in the end) -

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Now, **why is this error appearing on his server? What should be done to prevent/treat this error.**
If I need to ask these updated questions separately, please let me know.

Comment: on which line you are getting the exception?

Comment: Probably that one: `topic_id = json.getInt("value");`

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari can you show your JSON OutPut.?

Comment: Which line is DailyTestFragment.java:786?

Comment: @legr3c line 786 is topic_id = json.getInt("value");

Comment: @SilentKiller thanks for highlight. Yes {"value":1} is my output. Sorry i am medical doctor. learning android is my hobby. Apparently I will have to learn how use mini-markdown :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like json is null on following line, which is giving you the NullPointerException.

```
topic_id = json.getInt("value");
```

I think this is because your parser is having issues parse the json. I wrote a quick python script and tried to parse the page and it failed as well. For some reason, the response I get from http://medicalguru.in/android/tod.php is:

```
\xef\xbb\xbf{"value":1}
```

I am not sure why the \xef\xbb\xbf bytes are there, but they are likely causing the problem.

edit: a quick google search says it is the UTF-8 BOM. If you remove it your android code should work.

edit2: I put an example json on http://mwesly.com/test. Try hitting that json to see if your android code is correct. If it works, it means there is a problem with your endpoint, not your android code.

edit3: example of using loopj:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://mwesly.com/test", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {
        // do something with the json
        int value = json.getInt("value");
    }
});
```

I'm going to head to bed, if you still haven't solved this problem when I wake up, I'll give it another look. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Hi, I tried with your link.. but error in logcat is same :(

Comment: Well then the good news is that you know the error is in your android code. I think it is probably in your `getJSONFromUrl` method. It is returning null, which means that it is having a problem loading the page. I would recommend uncommenting the error logs and trying to figure out where it is failing.

That said, I generally use the loopj library for async http requests. http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ It is very nice and I have added an example of using it in my answer.

Comment: I will try your new edit, and get back to you.. meanwhile I have edited my original question for you, so that you can have a look at php code too. you talked about UTF-8 BOM. after your mention, I read about it. But can you please tell me how to avoid/remove it. I use Notepad++ for php and don't know python so how can i know if my output is changed than expected. gn.

Comment: please read my edit 2. Strange that, after changing chrSet, code is working on my-url while it's showing error in your json. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following `getJSONFromUrl` method:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        return new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you properly.
Do you mean I should the line mentioned by you in JSONObject doInBackground?
 If yes, I tried, but says -"httpResponse cannot be resolved"... I dont know if it makes a difference I am using async in fragment.

Comment: if i use your getJSONFromUrl I get this error (after pressing ctrl+shift+o) - The method JSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONParser. And if i correct it by creating method "private JSONObject JSONObject(String string)" I dont know how to use it? It seems operating on human patients is easier than android coding :(

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari I've made a small typo (forgot `new`)

Comment: was unable to use your code as such, getting err - "unhandled" exception type jsonexception. so tried using try catch for the return... but my bad luck, stil same err.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at in.medicalguru.DailyTestFragment$getTopicId.onPostExecute(DailyTestFragment.java:786)
at in.medicalguru.DailyTestFragment$getTopicId.onPostExecute(DailyTestFragment.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: do you have your own `JsonParser` class or it's built-in?

Comment: i have a separate class named JASONParser, but i dont think it overrides any built-in functions. i have pasted it's full source code on pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/VfpFHJyz). It was the original source, then i replaced "getjsonfromurl" with the one you provided. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: one more attempt: try to replace `jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://medicalguru.in/android/tod.php");` with `jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://www.medicalguru.in/android/tod.php");`

Comment: i am really very sorry. you are continuously trying to help me. but emergency call at hospital. will try for sure once i get back and reply. thx.

Comment: I tried with both, with or without www. But i found problem a bit... please read edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
private JSONObject jObj = null;
private JSONArray JArr = null;
```

and then after;

```
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("your url is here");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json_value = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    try {
              JArr = new JSONArray(json_value);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jObj = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < JArr.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jObj = JArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    topic_id = jObj.getInt("value");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried to use your code, but will you please have a look at it again. the line "String json_value = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("your url");"  is not a String. and also, where is 'json' defined used in line - "JArr = new JSONArray(json);" ? Thanks.

Comment: tried with your new answer, getting error "The method getJSONFromUrl(String) in the type JSONParser is not applicable for the arguments (URL)", if i try to correct this.. it requires to change the type of url in class "JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url)", which in turn need another change in the class..

Comment: you must write your url above instead of "your url is here". jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url); don't edit this part.

Comment: YES sir, i did write my url at mentioned space. it was the err mentioned above, i was getting on line "String json_value = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);" sorry for any confusion caused.